# Template Engine to create XML and Json in PHP

Tags: php, xml, json, template-engine

I am looking to see if there are any Template engines that could render any given data to XML and Json. The data would come from a combination of SQL queries and calculations/added fields. The data wouldn't necessarily use all the SQL data because some parts of it will be used for the calculations.
I need something generic that I can use to point to a template made for that specific output. There will be several pages using their own output.

I am aware that PHP has its own template engine, but I have never gotten it to work with json very well, especially when it comes to collections of attributes.

Comment: why don't you create an array with your data (structured per type of your needs), convert that to xml using `SimpleXMLElement` or json with `json_encode` and return with appropriate headers?

Comment: Because can not predict the depth of arrays or the count. When I have tried arrays I have to predetermine how many lists of attributes I am getting. Some sub-arrays would have to loop x number of times depending on the results of that particular field.